# Strange IP/domain in MySQL logs - cause for concern?

Tags: mysql, security, vps

I was going through my MySQL error logs on my VPS, and found something curious:

```
140206  9:40:05 [Warning] IP address '173.244.206.13' has been resolved
to the host name '173.244.206.13.static.midphase.com', which 
resembles IPv4-address itself.
```

I thought the mention of `midphase.com` was strange, as I had never heard of that before. Is there cause for alarm that I'm seeing an unfamiliar domain in my MySQL logs?

Comment: Retracting my earlier comment, I notice you said VPS in your question.   I guess whether or not you need to be concerned depends on whether or not you are certain where all of the legitimate traffic on your VPS should come from.

Comment: @DavidWilkins I should be the only user with access to the actual environment. Obviously traffic to my site will come from all over, but the fact that this appeared in the DB logs is what alarmed me a bit. The only other thing I could think of was that I was trying to connect to the DB via SequelPro from home, but that wouldn't explain the midphase domain, I don't think.

Comment: No it wouldn't, unless you were spoofing your own IP address.  That IP tracks back to a hosting provider (unless it is being spoofed)  so I guess the next question is what is the nature of the error in your log?  If it is a connection error, you could just have a bot programmed to find open databases.

Comment: The only thing the error in your question indicates is that MySQL is complaining about DNS resolution.  You'll have to determine where the connection is originating from and what it is trying to do to get anywhere further.  Sorry I cannot be more help

Answer (score 0):

This from Amazon:

> If you don't own that IP address, please review your security group settings and make sure that the network authorizations are restrictive enough. I don't know if it's your case, but it's worth mentioning that we recommend strongly against using "0.0.0.0/0" authorization in combination with RDS instances.

I hope this helps you.